# Displaying data using *ngFor in an expansion panel

Tags: angular

I am trying to render a list of posts in angular 11 using *ngFor but for some reason, nothing gets displayed, but when I remove the *ngFor and just display some data manually without looping through a list it works.

On the console, I found this error ( mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl )

Here is the code I used on the post-list.component.html :

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header> {{ post.title }}</mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

post-list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./post-list.component.css']
})

export class PostListComponent   {
  posts = [
    {title:'First Post',content : 'This is the First post'},
    {title:'Second Post',content : 'This is the Second post'},
    {title:'Third Post',content : 'This is the Third post'}
  ];


}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon'
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {PostCreateComponent} from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {PostListComponent} from './posts/post-list/post-list.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

post-create.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field [(ngModel)]="enteredTitle">
    <input matInput type="text" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredContent"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddPost()">
    Save Post
  </button>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the *ngFor in the mat-expension-panel instead of the mat-accordion:

```
<mat-accordion multi="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header> {{ post.title }}</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{ post.content }}
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

In post-create.component.html you have to put [(ngModel)] in the `input` tag instead of the `mat-form-field` :

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="enteredTitle" type="text" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredContent"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddPost()">
    Save Post
  </button>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: I tried that for some reason it did not change a thing

Comment: i tried it in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9tz9ga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and it worked. Can you share more details about it, do you have some error message in log or something else ?

Comment: I get this error in the console core.js:6142 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: Can you share more code from your html file ?

Comment: That's everything I have in the HTML file I will share the app.module.ts

Comment: I don't think that this error is related to `PostListComponent`. Are you using `FormGroup` somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes am using it in PostCreatComponent as well, I will add the HTML file for it

Comment: @Souhail I edited my answer, does it work for you ?